# Using CNAME to point to another domain to save IP addresses

Tags: domain-name-system, cname-record

I have one server which I'm hosting a handful of sites on.

Currently, each site has it's domain hosted by an independent provider and each has an A record pointing to the server's IP address.

But if I want to change the server in the future, I will have to go back an update each IP address in each DNS record.

Is it possible to use a CNAME record on each domain to point to another domain that I control directly?

This is so I can update the IP address in 1 place myself and not have to get all these other DNS providers to update their records separately?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

That's exactly the point of a CNAME. A CNAME does not need to point to a DNS in the same zone, it can point to any DNS name registered with any nameserver.

What it means for your clients is an additional DNS lookup on the NS for the other host, but that's a tiny price to pay for the majority of websites on the internet.

Comment: normally it's the recursive server that will perform that additional lookup, not the stub resolver in the client.

Answer (score 33):

Per Farseeker's answer, yes, this is (sort of) what `CNAME` records are for.

**However** whilst you can use this to point `www.example.net` to `www.example.com`, you *can't* use it to point `example.net` on its own (i.e. without the `www` prefix) to something else.

This is because `example.net` must also have an `SOA` record and `NS` records, and it's not legal in DNS to have a `CNAME` present at the same part of the tree as any other records (DNSSEC keys excepted).

The "sort of" qualifier above, is because strictly speaking the `CNAME` record introduces the "left hand side" as an *alias* for the target of the `CNAME` record, where that target is actually the "canonical name".

Hence if you see e.g.:

```
www.example.net IN CNAME www.example.com.
```

It is *not* saying that `www.example.net` should be "redirected" to `www.example.com`, it's saying that the `www.example.net` is *another name for* `www.example.com`.

Comment: "example.net must also have an SOA record". Some people cheat: look at lrnskls.com.

Comment: it's a nasty hack, and they'll have a huge problem should they ever want to DNSSEC sign it.

Comment: +1 this is a good point and one of the bigger flaws (and reason why none of my sites can be used www-less as those domains also needs an MX record, prohibiting this).

Answer (score 3):

Yes it is possible.

That's how I do my experimental web servers that also have dynamic IPs (though seldom changed).

Answer (score 0):

> I will have to go back an update each
>   IP address in each DNS record.

Well, CNAMEs are indeed a possible solution (see Alnitak's reply for a limit of the CNAMEs) but there is another one: instead of managing your zone files by hand, create a ten-lines program (Perl / Python / Ruby / cpp / m4 / whatever) which will generate the zone files from a master (a text file, a XML file, a DBMS, whatever)

That way, your IP address can be in only one place. When it changes, just re-run the program.