# is CNAME faster than serving directly from another hosted sub-domain?

Tags: domain-name-system, web-server, domain, cname-record, dns-zone

If a domain exists say **blahblah.com** and has a subdomain **cdn.blahblah.com**, For this scenario, which one of the following two is `faster` for serving(least server usage) and delivering(fastest for end-user) the website on http protocol?

1. `cdn.blahblah.com` has **`CNAME`** to `blahblah.com`, so that it also loads/serves same static files
2. `cdn.blahblah.com` is hosted on the same server with same home directory as that of main domain `blahblah.com`  (Meaning that `blahblah.com` and `cdn.blahblah.com` have same `A records` and both point to same dir)

Please note that I have added `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` headers for both `cdn.blahblah.com` and `blahblah.com`
&& sole reason for using sub domain is to make the static traffic *cookieless*. (No usage for SPF/TXT or SRV for cdn subdomain)

p.s. This question is not a duplicate of [Many domains/sites hosted on same server, CNAME alternatives to avoid writing same IP in DNS?](https://serverfault.com/questions/481500/many-domains-sites-hosted-on-same-server-cname-alternatives-to-avoid-writing-sa)

Answer (score 2):

"A" records are generally faster than CNAME records. A CNAME is like an alias, it results in a second DNS lookup for the domain name specified in the CNAME. However, the difference will be small.

You should test to see if the subdomain is faster. If you use https / https2 this split domain technique could theoretically slow things down. http2 allows pushing resources not yet requested and sends multiple resources over the same connection.